# GWT upload form causing browser back to freeze page in Chrome

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, browser-history

We have an upload form in GWT we use to upload files. It works fine when uploading files, but if we upload more than two files in a row, and then click the browser back button, a strange thing happens. The page disappears, eventually reloads itself, and then freezes. No buttons are clickable until it has been reloaded. This happens in Chrome 39, but not the other browser I've tried it in (and old version of firefox).

Why would the form panel submit do something like that? How can I fix it? I can't seem to find a way to remove the form submit from history, or a simple way to upload files without using GWT's FormPanel and FileUpload. I can't just reload the page after every file upload, because refreshes are very slow.

Here's the code that creates the relevant parts of the panels:

```
FormPanel uploadForm = new FormPanel();
uploadForm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
uploadForm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
uploadForm.setAction(servletPath + destinationUrl);

FileUpload fileInput = new FileUpload();
uploadForm.add(fileInput.asWidget());
```

When the user clicks to upload a selected file, we use:

```
uploadForm.submit();
```

The [GWTUploadProject](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) is not a solution, as it works arguably worse. If you try to click back after uploading on their [examples page](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/), it shows an extra thumbnail of the previously uploaded image!

Comment: Could you describe more detailed how to reproduce the issue with gwtupload example, I'm the author of the library and would like to fix the problem if I can reproduce.

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino Sure. Go to [this page](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/index.html). Click first "example". Click "choose files" select a file, and click send. Do that three times. (You should now see three thumbnails at the bottom.) Click browser back button. A fourth thumbnail will appear. This also works with the single file uploader. In Chrome 39, not sure about other browsers.

Comment: I see, I will investigate what is happening

Comment: I have fixed the issue in gwtupload, can you check it the demo page works for you?

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino I'm actually still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue. Does your chrome freezes using my demo? or just showing the thumbnail again?

Comment: It doesn't freeze, it just generates an extra thumbnail per back button clicked.

Comment: It should be fixed right now, let me know.

Comment: Did you have the time to test the demo, if it works for you I can post the hack here.

Comment: Yup, that seems to have fixed the issue. Would be good to know the hack!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new `FormPanel` it creates as well an `Frame` in order to send the output of the form to it when it is submitted and not change the current page.

The problem is that the browser puts the focus on this iframe, happening that using browser history, this enters in this iframe re-firing the on-submit event.

You have different options here:

- Remove the `ChangeHandler` to your `FileUpload` when the uploading finishes.
- Remove the `FormPanel` from the page and create a new one, in each uploading.
- Detach the `FormPanel`'s `Frame` and reattach it after the upload, so as you remove it from the history stack. This is a big hack but probably the only one if you want to reuse the same panel again,  it is the approach being used in the [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) library.

```java
reatachIframe(uploadForm);

private native static void reatachIframe(FormPanel form) /*-{
  var i = form.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel::synthesizedFrame;
  var o = i.onload;
  i.onload = undefined;
  var p = i.parentElement;
  p.removeChild(i);
  p.appendChild(i);
  i.onload = o;
}-*/;
```

Comment: @FrançoisWauquier `reatachIframe` is commented in github source code. Is it no more required?

Comment: I had the same issue. What i did was remove the forms from the panel and immediately add them back. Which is your third suggestion